# Exception while mapping composite type using Npgsql in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql, composite-types

We map **composite type** in our C# application using **npgsql** (open source postgres ado.net provider for C#).

```
NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally<SomeCompositeType>("some_type", new NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator());
```

We map it every time globally before executing postgres query or opening connection. It works fine mostly but sometimes we get error.

**Exception we are getting**

> System.NotSupportedException: The CLR type Entities.CompositeTypes.SomeCompositeType isn't supported by Npgsql or your PostgreSQL. If you wish to map it to a PostgreSQL composite type you need to register it before usage, please refer to the documentation.

Also we do not make any changes at postgres db level for this composite type but still get this error sometimes.

Here is the pseudo code we are using for this.

```
public void CreateData(int value)
{
    NpgsqlConnection.MapCompositeGlobally<SomeCompositeType>("some_type", new NpgsqlSnakeCaseNameTranslator());

    var parameters = new NpgsqlParameter[]
    {
       new NpgsqlParameter{ParameterName = "p_value", NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlDbType.Composite, Value = value,SpecificType=typeof(SomeCompositeType[])}
    }
 }

 excuteQuery(query, parameters); // inside it we open connection & execute query
```

Current Npgsql version we are using is **Npgsql 3.2.7**

Comment: Are you sure you're always mapping your composite *before* ever doing a query? This is usually a case of a race condition between the global mapping and some query which happens to get executed before the mapping.

Comment: Yes, we always map it before executing query

Comment: I haven't used Npgsql before, but at least with EntityFramework you don't map custom types as arrays, even if the type in the database is a table type; so `SpecificType=typeof(SomeCompositeType[])` looks a bit suspicious to me...perhaps it should be `SpecificType=typeof(SomeCompositeType)`?

Comment: What is the correct way of mapping composite type and place?

Comment: @Moniv, I don't know what the correct way is for npgsql, only that it might be worth trying `SomeCompositeType` instead of `SomeCompositeType[]` for the type assigned to `SpecificType`. As I mentioned, I've never used npgsql before.

Comment: Have you tried omitting `SpecificType` altogether? If you mapped the composite, then `SpecificType` should be entirely optional.

Comment: ok, will try this.